# Pick a row with the latest step completed by the customer?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say i have two tables, Table 1 contains customers, Table 2 contains steps completed by a customer. I want the latest step that the customer is in and the status of that step.

Table 1:Customer

| customer_id | customer_name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Alex |
| 456 | Baldwin |

Table 2:Action

| action_id | customer_id | type | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X11 | 123 | step 3 | email sent |
| X12 | 123 | step 4 | email sent |
| X13 | 123 | step 4 | pending |
| X14 | 123 | step 4 | completed |
| X15 | 456 | step 1 | pending |
| X16 | 456 | step 1 | email sent |
| X17 | 456 | step 1 | completed |
| X18 | 456 | step 2 | pending |
| X19 | 456 | step 2 | email sent |

There are other Types & Statuses in the table.

```
select customer_id, customer_name, Action.type, Action.status
from Customer 
left join Action on Customer.customer_id = Action.customer_id 
where Action.action_id in 
(Select max(action_id) 
from Action 
where type in ('step 1','step 2', step 3', 'step 4') 
and status in ('pending','email_sent','completed'))
```

Expected result :

| customer_id | customer_name | type | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Alex | step 4 | completed |
| 456 | Baldwin | step 2 | email sent |

Normally, this query would generate the expected result, but in this case, actions got created in no particular order. But the user would be going in a particular order.

step 1 pending -> step 1 email sent -> step 1 completed -> step 2 pending ->..etc.,

I need a query to know where in the above order is the customer presently. It should return the highest type & status of each customer.

Comment: What is your MySql version? `Window functions` offer the easiest method. Your data however has issues, there is no integer or date column by which to determine "latest".

Comment: There are date columns such as created on & completed on in the action table. but due to some programming bug, the actions which actually get created sequentially, got jumbled. That's the reason why my query isn't picking up things properly.

Comment: MSSQL Version - 5.6.49

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select Customer.customer_id, customer_name, Action.type, Action.status
from Customer 
    Inner Join 
    (
        Select Action.customer_id, max(action_id) As HighestAction
        from Action 
        Group By customer_id
    )As CustomerTopAction ON Customer.customer_id = CustomerTopAction.customer_id
    Inner Join Action On Customer.customer_id = Action.customer_id And CustomerTopAction.HighestAction = Action.action_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions like this:

```
select customer_id, customer_name, Action.type, Action.status
from Customer c left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by type desc) as seqnum 
      from Action a
      where type in ('step 1', 'step 2', 'step 3', 'step 4') and
            status in ('pending', 'email_sent', 'completed'))
     ) a
     on c.customer_id = a.customer_id and seqnum = 1;
```

In older versions of MySQL, variables are an alternative:

```
select customer_id, customer_name, Action.type, Action.status
from Customer c left join
     (select a.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = customer_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := customer_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from (select a.*
            from Action a
            where type in ('step 1', 'step 2', 'step 3', 'step 4') and
                  status in ('pending', 'email_sent', 'completed'))
            order by customer_id, type desc
           ) a cross join
           (select @c := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) a
     on c.customer_id = a.customer_id and seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Window functions are not supported in the version that we are using. So is there any workaround for that?